# Cannot insert rows into Google Cloud Bigquery Table, raises AssertionError

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have an issue with streaming data into my bigquery table. According to [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery), you should be able to stream data with the following python code:

```
rows_to_insert = [
    (u'Phred Phlyntstone', 32),
    (u'Wylma Phlyntstone', 29),
]

errors = client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)  # API request

assert errors == []
```

So I have done this and I have set up my table reference the correct way. The funny thing is, my code raises an AssertionError, but there is no documentation on this error type.

The only reason I see this error happen is that in this example, the string input has a "u" written before it. My input doesn't. I don't know why this "u" is added in the example.

Can someone please help me and clear this up for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `assert errors == []` raises AssertionError. try using `print(errors)` to see what is wrong.

Comment: Thnx! I'm missing fields lol, not sure how that happened, but let's find out